# Probability of most frequent x substrings

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a string of length *N* and I have found *x* most frequently occuring (distinct) substrings of length L (*with condition than they occur atleast thrice in the string*).

Size of alphabet is 4.

I am trying to calculate the probability of it but not been able to make any formula as there are too many factors to consider there. Can anyone help please. Thanks so much

Comment: What is the size of your alphabet?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri 4. Updated the question

Comment: I am not quite sure your question even makes sense. Are the characters of the length $N$ string uniformly random?

Comment: Almost uniformly random. You can easily assume that